# Does the imbalance in my data affect model quality in this case?

Tags: loss-functions, unbalanced-classes, roc, auc

I have two datasets, used for classification task: training and validation one.

Both of them are equally imbalanced, with about 24% of target value equal 1 and 75% of target value equal 0.

I am using ROC AUC metric to measure quality of my model. So, knowing that ROC AUC is using true positive rate and false positive rate, I wonder, does this imbalance affect my model's quality? Should I do something with it, or using ROC AUC is already enough?

Comment: Probably not, unless the dataset is very small.  Whether the ROC AUC is already enough depends on the aims of the analysis (AUROC essentially measures the quality of the *ranking* of the data according to their propensity for belonging to the majority class, so if that kind of ranking is important for your application, it is a good criterion).

Comment: Also a 24-76(?) split is not very imbalanced, probably not something to worry about.